# What is the correct way to parse JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON string coming back from a Node JS Service:

```
"{\"success\":true,\"isavailable\":true}"
```

When I try to use json_decode() in the PHP I get the following on a var_dump:

```
string '{"success":true,"isavailable":true}' (length=35)
```

So, I set about to do the following:

```
$str = str_replace("\"{", "'{", $str);
$str = str_replace("}\"", "}'", $str);
$str = str_replace('\"','"',$str);
```

When I do this I get a Syntax Error from Return Last Error and a Value of NULL.

So, what is the correct way to parse this JSON string in PHP?

Comment: `json_decode` works for me: http://codepad.org/LIBC8ihP

Comment: `json_decode` is only available in php 5.2.0 + ?

Comment: @AlexLittlejohn Why would you be using a version older than 5.2.0?

Comment: @Todd: are you sure you're dumping the decoded string, rather than the JSON string? If so, it looks like the string is double-encoded, in which case you could apply `json_encode` twice.

Comment: I am sure, I believe my problem was double encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution (assuming the input is exactly what is in the OP) is to use `trim()` to get rid of the leading and trailing double quotes after calling `stripslashes()`:

```
$str = '"{\"success\":true,\"isavailable\":true}"';
$str = trim( stripslashes( $str), '"');
var_dump( json_decode( $str));
```

Now, [you get](http://viper-7.com/y8fyeI):

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["isavailable"]=> bool(true) }
```

I've also confirmed that this string appears to be double-encoded, so it can also be properly decoded with:

```
$str = '"{\"success\":true,\"isavailable\":true}"';
var_dump( json_decode( json_decode( $str)));
```

Comment: json_decode(stripslashes($json_string)); is sufficient as well I guess. The extra double quotes seen will not be actually part of the JSON string.

Comment: because you are actually using double quotes twice in the string. the actual string will not contain it twice.

Comment: I'm tempted to believe it is in the string twice, given the wording of the OP.

Comment: I have faced such an issue earlier, so know that how it exactly looks. Maybe for him it is something else...

Answer (score 0):

use

```
json_decode(stripslashes($json_string));
```

Comment: $a = '{\"success\":true,\"isavailable\":true}';

var_dump(json_decode(stripslashes($a)));

this gives the right object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = json_decode("{\"success\":true,\"isavailable\":true}");
echo $obj->success;
echo $obj->isavailable;
```

**Result:**

```
11
```

Here `1` represents `true` (the actual value in your json) eg truthy value.

You can see a demo in this [working example](http://codepad.org/kGxUNabC).

Comment: I get Trying to get property of non-object Error

Answer (score 0):

Your input is invalid, Assuming:

```
$this = '"{\"success\":true,\"isavailable\":true}"';
```

is what you really have.

So it isn't really a json_decode problem, but rather the slashes and the trailing quotes.

You can fix it by replacing, or trimming like it was mentioned above.

```
$obj = json_decode(trim(stripslashes('"{\"success\":true,\"isavailable\":true}\"'), '"'));
```

To acess it just do:

```
$obj->success
```

and

```
$obj->isavailable
```

you'll get 1 as true is a boolean.

But personally you should look into escaping the response, as to avoid these 'hacks' to the JSON string. things as slashes and quotes, shouldn't be sent unescaped.

If it's your own JSON response of course.

Answer (score -1):

`$parsed = json_decode($whatever);`

Comment: Why the downvote? It was the first answer and it was correct.

Comment: @Joe: Possibly because Todd mentions he tried `json_decode`, but it resulted in a string rather than an object.

Comment: Point taken. Having said that, there's no reason this shouldn't work.